# error with numbers dropping decimal places in c

Tags: c, console, line, rounding

I am in a beginner c class and when I run my code it drops some decimal places.  According to my handwritten equation of the same type it should equal 99.5 can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//create the number variable
double number = 0;

//function prototypes
double get_input();
double get_next(double one, double two);
void print_result(void);
int main(){
  //get all the input needed
  double x_two = get_input();
  double x_one = get_input();
  //calculate third
  double x_three = get_next(x_one,x_two);
  //calculate fourth
  double x_four = get_next(x_three,x_two);
  //calulate fith and set to number
  number = get_next(x_four,x_three);
  //print the result
  print_result();
}
double get_input(void){
  double number = 0;
  //prompt the user for the information needed
  printf("Please enter a value > ");
  //take the user info and pass it back
  scanf("%lf",&number);
 return number;




}
double get_next(double minus_one, double minus_two){
  double number = (minus_two/2)+(3*minus_one);
  return number;

}

void print_result(void){

  printf("The result is: %lf",number);


}
```

The equation is given as such
Xn =
X<sub>n−2</sub>/2 + (3 * x<sub>n-1</sub>)

the numbers I plug in for n-2 is 2 and n-3 is 3

Comment: `double get_input(void)` needs to have `return number;` at its end. Right now the function declares a return type but provides no such data, and thus invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: May be unrelated, but your `get_input` function needs to `return number;`.

Comment: I added the return number; and still end up with getting the number 98 vs 99.5

Comment: is there some reason there are *two* definitions of the same three functions at the end of your source list?

Comment: Sorry when I edited to put in the equation I must've pasted that part again

Comment: You aren't consistent when calling `get_next`. You've got `one,two`, `three,two`, and `four,three`. Either the first is backwards, or the other two are backwards. Also, as a user I would expect to enter `one` before entering `two`, but you've got it the other way round.

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what it was.  I really appreciate all your folks help.  Hopefully I can get to the point I can pay it forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your get_input() needs to return a value. `return number;`